# How to fix margin in report using latex in overleaf

Tags: margins, geometry

I am trying to write a thesis taken from one of the overleaf templates on the internet. When I write it margin is not working properly.
I need to keep margins,
left=   40 mm,
right=  40 mm,
top=    15 mm,
bottom= 20 mm,

Here is the code;

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{ucetd}[2022/07/11 thesis]
\etdArg{a4paper}{\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper}{report}}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.75in} % + foot skip (0.25) = 9.00in
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.2in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.2in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.2in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0.2in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.2in}
\setlength{\footskip}{0.3in}
\setlength{\hfuzz}{0.2pt}
\let\oldtableofcontents = \tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{
  \begin{singlespace}
    \oldtableofcontents
  \end{singlespace}
}
```

I have tried to solve this error. But still, nothing changed. I have attached the image of this. You can see the margin spaces are not working properly. I hope you all will give me suggestions to solve this error.

[image]

Comment: Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet. Besides, what has you question to do with [tag:latex3]?

Answer (score 1):

Did You try a `geometry` package?

See here: [link](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Page_size_and_margins)